# LazyInitializationException in RESTORE_VIEW (improper PersistentSet instantiation)

Tags: hibernate, jsf, jpa, drag-and-drop, icefaces

I'm getting started to use IceFaces and had encountered a problem when trying drag'n'drop support.

```
IceFaces 2.0.0
JSF 2.0
Mojarra 2.0.2 (FCS b10) (JSF reference implementation)
Spring 3.0.3
Hibernate 3.5.1-Final
JPA 2.0 (with OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter)
```

The problem is `LazyInitializationException` while dropping. My first conclusion was an incorrect persistence context lifecycle management settings, but after some hours of playing with settings, dependencies and debugging I have found strange thing: `JSF` implementation is creating `PersistentSet` instance by reflection with default constructor (!) in `RESTORE_VIEW phase` and trying to add values to it. This action causes `LazyInitializationException` because `PersistentSet` is created as a simple collection like `ArrayList` and not configured properly (session not set).

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException
                                        (AbstractPersistentCollection.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected
                                        (AbstractPersistentCollection.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.add(PersistentSet.java:212)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreAttachedState(UIComponentBase.java:1582)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.restoreState(ComponentStateHelper.java:290)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1444)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.UISeries.restoreState(UISeries.java:642)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.PanelSeries.restoreState(PanelSeries.java:138)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$2.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:231)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:147)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.UISeries.visitTree(UISeries.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:333)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.UISeries.visitColumnsAndRows(UISeries.java:898)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.UISeries.visitTree(UISeries.java:832)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:223)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:177)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:430)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:143)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
javax.faces.FacesException: Unexpected error restoring state for component with id castle-list:j_idt12:castle-resident-list.  
Cause: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed.
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$2.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:239)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:147)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.UISeries.visitTree(UISeries.java:814)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:333)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.UISeries.visitColumnsAndRows(UISeries.java:898)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.UISeries.visitTree(UISeries.java:832)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.restoreView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:223)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:177)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:430)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:143)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:110)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: 
                    failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException
                                        (AbstractPersistentCollection.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected
                                        (AbstractPersistentCollection.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.add(PersistentSet.java:212)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreAttachedState(UIComponentBase.java:1582)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.restoreState(ComponentStateHelper.java:290)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1444)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.UISeries.restoreState(UISeries.java:642)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.panelseries.PanelSeries.restoreState(PanelSeries.java:138)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl$2.visit(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:231)
    ... 34 more
```

#### This code of JSF implementation Library contains a problem:

(javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.java:1566-1591):

```
if (stateObj instanceof List) {
    List<StateHolderSaver> stateList = (List<StateHolderSaver>) stateObj;
    Collection<Object> retCollection = null;
    StateHolderSaver collectionSaver = stateList.get(0);
    Class collectionClass = (Class) collectionSaver.restore(context);
    try {
        retCollection = (Collection<Object>) collectionClass.newInstance();     //(*)
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.SEVERE)) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown object type");
    }
    for (int i = 1, len = stateList.size(); i < len; i++) {
        try {
            retCollection.add(stateList.get(i).restore(context));       //(**)
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            if (LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.SEVERE)) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, cce.toString(), cce);
            }
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown object type");
        }
    }
    result = retCollection;
}
```

- `*` in my case "collectionClass" is "org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet".
- `**` "retCollection.add" invocation results LazyInitializationException

Simple maven project can be [downloaded here](http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/downloadAttach/3631.page). just run it as web app, create few entries in "Heroes" and "Castles" section and then try to bind them by drag'n'drop in "Castles & Heroes" section.

It isn't clear, who is responsible for this issue - JSF RI, IceFaces or my hands=)
I had post this problem on IceFaces and Oracle forums:

```
http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/18539.page
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9328036
```

Advise me some workarounds or point to my errors, please=)

Comment: It's a strange problem indeed. I've never had it with JSF though. I think that when using EAGER collections hibernate should not create its collections. Can you check that

Comment: I had checked it again. It should=) PersistentSet created in both cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LazyInitializationException with CDI Managed Bean and Stateful Session Bean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802854/lazyinitializationexception-with-cdi-managed-bean-and-stateful-session-bean)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar promblem with primefaces p:selectManyCheckbox component.
Maybe not exactly your case, but adding **f:attribute name="collectionType"** to component solve the problem.

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox value="#{offerEditBean.selectedFloors}" converter="ait.entity.converter" layout="pageDirection">
    <f:attribute name="collectionType" value="java.util.HashSet" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{offerEditBean.floors}" var="item" itemValue="#{item}" itemLabel="#{item.name}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

FYI: Instance variable selectedFloors initialized from entities @OneToMany Set property.

So, answering your question, it is mostly a JSF issue.

I found this solution here http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30765